# Show links when presenting flagged answers

Tags: bug, moderator-tools, flags

I just got a flagged answer on UX consisting only of a reference to a blog article with (seemingly) no link to said blog article. Hovering over the text, there's no link, nor is there link styling. I promptly deleted it, since what's the point of an answer about a link with no link?

[image]

Clicking through to the answer on the question page itself, turns out "a great article about SUS" was linked text. It wasn't a full answer, just a comment anyway, but it really would have been nice to know it was a "link-only" answer instead of a "vague reference to not a link" answer.

Comment: It's kinda funny that the main complaint is you can't see a link...and I don't see one here either :) Always link to the example if you can, makes tracking down what the problem is *much* easier.

Comment: @NickCraver well I already handled the flag so it's gone, it's [this answer](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/4763/standardized-free-survey-besides-sus/4765#4765) and I raised a flag on it again so you can see it at http://ux.stackexchange.com/admin/dashboard with a "testing something" flag

Comment: What if you expand the answer (by clicking the arrow)? On the 10k tools, that displays the link, without requiring us to leave the flag queue.